# Get last row of many matrices (ASCII text files) and create a new matrix from these rows

Tags: matlab, shell, matrix, ascii

I have over a thousand matrices (6 x 2000, ASCII files, comma delimited) that I generated from MATLAB.  I want to get the last row of each matrix / text file and save them in a new matrix / text file.  The text files have crazy names so when I load them I can name them whatever.  Right now I would do this to achieve my goal:

```
% A = load('crazyname.txt');
% B = load('crazynameagain.txt');
% C = load('crazynameyetagain.txt');

A = [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 1 1 1];
B = [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 2 2 2];
C = [5 5 5; 5 5 5; 3 3 3];

D(1,:)=A(end,:);
D(2,:)=B(end,:);
D(3,:)=C(end,:);
```

I will create each command (e.g. load, building *D* step by step) in Excel by combining text cells to create a command.  Is there a better way to do this?  Could I load / assign the matrices with a name that would better suit them to be used in a for loop?  Or is some other MATLAB command that would facilitate this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you have all the `csv` files in folder `d:/tmp`, each contains `6x2000`:

```
folder = 'd:/tmp';
files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.csv'));
res = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) csvread(fullfile(folder, x), 5, 0), {files.name}', 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Note the arguments of `csvread()`.

**Edit:** if the delimiter is space `' '`:

```
res = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) dlmread(fullfile(folder, x), ' ', 5, 0), {files.name}', 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Comment: As I mentioned I have text files.  Can I use `text read`  I tried to do so and get the following errors.  Please advise. 

`Error using dataread
Third input must be empty or a format string.`

`Error in textread (line 176)
[varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:});`

`Error in @(x)textread(fullfile(folder,x),5,0)`


`Error in getfilestest2 (line 3)
res = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) textread(fullfile(folder, x), 5, 0), {files.name}', 'UniformOutput', false)); `

Comment: it doesn't matter what files extension you use. You can use `files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.txt'));` if you have `.txt` files. But it does matter in which format the data is stored inside the files.  What delimiter between numbers do you have in files?

Comment: you can use `dlmread()` instead of `csvread()` if you have other than comma delimiter. type: `help dlmread`

Comment: Thanks, they are space delimited.  I'll check out that.

Comment: Thanks for the update and please excuse my delay.  However, for example, if I run the modified script above on some space delimited text files that are 6 columns by 1050 rows, the output _res_ is 11 columns by [1045 (1050 - 5?) rows x number of text files]. So a directory with 3 text files has the output _res_ of 6x3135, whereas the desired output, the last row of each file, would be 6x3.  Please advise.  Thanks again.

Comment: you wrote that the files contain `6 x 2000` matrices. In any case, just set correct arguments to `dlmread()`, and arrange the output correctly. You can remove `cell2mat()` in order to see what is the output.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a common schema to the file names, you could use the dir function to get a list of them. From there, load them in one at a time and put them into your array. You also need to know how many there are first, to preallocate. This could be shrunk down after you are done. Put it all together, and you have something like this.

```
files=dir ('c:/somefolder/*.txt')
output=zeros(2000,length(files));
usedValue=false(zeros(1,length(files)));
for i=1:length(files)
    if (~files(i).isdir)
        dat=load(files(i).name);
        usedValue(i)=true;
        output(:,i)=dat(end,:);
    end
end
output=output(:,usedValue);
```

Note that you could put some additional checking on the files at the if statement, to make sure the file names are correct.

Comment: Hello, I get the following error: 

`Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`
`Error in getfilestest (line 8)` 

please advise, thanks.

Comment: I also fixed line 15 to `usedValue=false(zeros(1,length(files)));` and made the output `output=zeros(length(files),6);` as the would be the 6 columns for each of the last rows for each of the files to be processed, right?  However, I am still getting the same error code: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in getfilestest (line 20)
        output(:,i)=dat(end,:);`  
I tried changing that line to `output(i,:)=dat(end,:)` thinking that this might give me the row and all the columns, but this still resulted in the same error code.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, what is the output of `size(dat(end,:))`?

Comment: The output of `size(dat(end,:))` if I run the code as far it goes is a 1x2 double with value `[1,5]`, or where you asking me what I wanted the output to be? The desired output is the last row of each file (each row has 6 columns).  Thanks again